# 429 - Openai API Rate limit error with no usuage

Tags: openai-api, rate-limiting, large-language-model, http-status-code-429

I am recieving the following error. However, when I check my usuage on API dashboard, it says nothing and I have not used any credits. I am not sure why is this error occuring.. I am not even sure if the Quota resets monthly. What can I do about it?

openai.RateLimitError: Error code: 429 - {'error': {'message': 'You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details. For more information on this error, read the docs: [https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/error-codes/api-errors.'](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/error-codes/api-errors.%27), 'type': 'insufficient_quota', 'param': None, 'code': 'insufficient_quota'}}

I was trying to use Openai API key for my LLM powered application. I have not made enough calls to the API yet but I keep seeing this error

Comment: did you just signup? free quota has an expiration date